# manhua/manhwa: isekai, FL with redish/pinkish hair adopted by noble family

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics, isekai

I'm looking for a webcomic/webtoon/manhua/manhwa that I read this year.

I believe it's fairly new, 2019 or 2020 even.

It was about a girl that reincarnates in another world or remembers her past life. She was poor in both lives until she was adopted by a noble because her hair color was similar to the people of said noble family, and because the original daughter had disappeared. Her brothers mistreated her verbally and judged her a lot because she was supposed to be a replacement for their dear disappeared/dead daughter. Slowly they start treating her better because of her change in attitude. I think maybe she was a villainess??

*The oldest brother has black/dark blue hair and the other one has light pink hair.*

About the plot: she was avoiding death that I **think** she knew would soon come, it was also near her coming of age party, I believe (end of adolescence or young adult). There is no magic, that I remember at least. It's isekai, fantasy, drama and kinda western historical (the landscapes and clothes).

I read it in English, but I really don't know the original language.

It was full color and a long strip!

Answer (score 4):

> [Villains Are Destined to Die](https://mangadex.org/title/47754/death-is-the-only-ending-for-the-villainess) (aka Death Is The Only Ending For The Villainess): Written by the Author Gwongyeoeul.

Penelope Eckart reincarnated as the adopted daughter of Duke Eckart and the villainess of a reverse harem dating sim. The problem is, she entered the game at its hardest difficulty, and no matter what she does, death awaits her at every ending! Before the "real daughter" of Duke Eckart appears, she must choose one of the male leads and reach a happy ending in order to survive. But the two brothers always pick a fight with her over every little thing, as well as a crazy crown prince, whose routes all lead to death. There's even a magician who's enamoured with the female lead, and a loyal slave knight! But somehow, the favourability meters of the male leads increase the more she crosses the line with them!

This is Penelope’s survival story, who’s been dropped in an insane reverse harem dating sim!

> Derrick Eckart has more black than blue hair but could be classified as Navy

> Reynold Eckart has light pink hair